# Adding a syscall to FreeBSD without kldload

Tags: kernel, freebsd

How can I statically compile a `syscall` inside the kernel(or the appropriate libraries. not sure which one). I have seen https://wiki.freebsd.org/AddingSyscalls. But it doesn't state anywhere how to add my own source files, to FreeBSD's own for Compilation.

Answer (score 3):

If you're able to build a kernel module to add your syscall (as you imply in your title via "kldload"), you only need to do one additional step to have your kernel module be statically compiled into the kernel - list it in the kernel configuration file using a 'device' invocation.

For instance, looking at my `/usr/src/sys/amd64/conf/GENERIC` kernel config file, I see a device entry for `cpufreq`:

```
# CPU frequency control
device      cpufreq
```

In the `/usr/src/sys/modules/cpufreq` directory, I see the following Makefile:

```
hostname(/usr/src/sys/modules/cpufreq) # cat Makefile

.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../dev/cpufreq            \
        ${.CURDIR}/../../${MACHINE_CPUARCH}/cpufreq

KMOD=   cpufreq
SRCS=   ichss.c
SRCS+=  bus_if.h cpufreq_if.h device_if.h pci_if.h

.if ${MACHINE} == "i386" || ${MACHINE} == "amd64"
.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../x86/cpufreq

SRCS+=  acpi_if.h opt_acpi.h
SRCS+=  est.c hwpstate.c p4tcc.c powernow.c
.endif

.if ${MACHINE} == "i386"
SRCS+=  smist.c
.endif

.if ${MACHINE} == "powerpc"
.PATH:  ${.CURDIR}/../../powerpc/cpufreq
SRCS+= dfs.c
.endif

.include <bsd.kmod.mk>
```

And resolving that `${.CURDIR}/../../x86/cpufreq` turns us to `/usr/src/sys/x86/cpufreq`, where we finally find the source files for this module:

```
hostname(/usr/src/sys/x86/cpufreq) # ll
total 106
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    43K Jan 21  2014 est.c
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    13K Jan 21  2014 hwpstate.c
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   9.1K Jan 21  2014 p4tcc.c
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    23K Jun 11  2013 powernow.c
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel    12K Jun 11  2013 smist.c
```

Since there's a `device cpufreq` entry in my kernel config, I get the cpufreq module without a `kldload`

Comment: So the `device` entry in the Kernel Configuration maps to a directory `/usr/src/sys/modules` that is to be `make`d ?

Comment: That would seem to be the design, yes. However, there are two ways I see this working, and I'm not sure which is the actual design - either the binding happens based on directory names, or the binder scans all directories looking for Makefiles with `KMOD` definitions in them, as you see above in the cpufreq Makefile.